# Countdown timer image changer

Tags: android

I have an `ImageSwitcher` which i use to switch through some images which gets set in a countdown timer but the image switching is behaving "jumpy". That is the images are switching smoothly at first then start to randomly disappear skip images 
The expected order would be : 1->2->3->4 but the behavior is more like 1->3->1->4->1->2->3->1
where the numbers represent images in an array. Any advice or an alternate solution would be appreciated. Code below

```
public void bannerChanger(){

  timer = new CountDownTimer(10000L,3000L) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long perTick) {

            if(curBan < bannerPics.length){

                is.setImageResource(bannerPics[curBan]);
                curBan += 1; //field variable to get item from array
            }
            else{

                curBan = 0;
                is.setImageResource(bannerPics[curBan]);//imageswitcher
                curBan += 1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timer.start();
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: Simply use handler Instead of Timer

Comment: You know I was trying to but I kept getting an error about creating an abstract `handler();`